# Running status of application in Tomcat manager is true but got 404 not found?

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have deploy my application in IntelliJ by tomcat. The deploy process seem to be success when I got these logs:

```
[2020-12-17 01:36:54,245] Artifact CheckInService: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2020-12-17 01:36:54,245] Artifact CheckInService: Deploy took 152,785 milliseconds
```

But when I went to the link I got 404 error (I follow context link in my deployment). Therefore I have go to tomcat manager and saw that my CheckInService's running status is true.

What could be the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What **context** url is reported for this application in Tomcat manager app? Check that you open the correct url. The web path root url is taken from the Run Configuration **Application context** value:

[image]